# how to run migrate command above an existing database

Tags: laravel, migration

I'm new using laravel and artisan migration command, and I want to create migrate files from an existing database, how can I do that ?

Comment: I've found this tool to do it https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Answer (score 0):

Laravel does not currently support this. You'll have to manually create all those files based off your schema already in your DB.